# Plotting solutions of a difference equation

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations

I'm trying to reproduce Figure 2 of this [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.73.1553).

This plot is the solution of Eq. (7) of the paper, which is a difference equation, with an initial value given in Table 1. Here is its summary:

```
sol = RSolveValue[{p[n] == p[n - 1] ((0.356 n^2 + (2 - 9*0.356) n + 14*0.356 - 2)/(0.356 (n - 3) (n - 6 + 4/0.356))),
p[6] == 0.12517}, p[n], n];
```

To plot the above, we write:

```
DiscretePlot[sol[n], {n, 3, 12}]
```

It seems Mathematica cannot solve it in this way. Are there any other methods to solve difference equations with Mathematica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `sol` to

```
sol = RSolveValue[{p[n] == 
p[n - 1] ((0.356 n^2 + (2 - 9*0.356) n + 14*0.356 - 2)/(0.356 (n - 3) (n - 6 + 4/0.356))), p[6] == 0.12517},
p ,n]
```

and

```
DiscretePlot[sol[n], {n,0, 12}]
```

[image]

works as expected!

Comment: In my `RSolveValue[...,p,n]` instead of `p[n]` in yours.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[p, g];
g[n_] = ((0.356 n^2 + (2 - 9*0.356) n + 14*0.356 - 
      2)/(0.356 (n - 3) (n - 6 + 4/0.356)));
p[6] = 0.12517;
p[n_ /; n >= 6] := p[n - 1] g[n];
p[n_ /; n < 6] := p[n + 1]/g[n + 1]
DiscretePlot[p[n], {n, 3, 20}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

```
data = RecurrenceTable[{p[n] == 
    p[n - 1] ((0.356 n^2 + (2 - 9*0.356) n + 14*0.356 - 
         2)/(0.356 (n - 3) (n - 6 + 4/0.356))), p[6] == 0.12517}, 
  p[n], {n, 6, 20}]
ListPlot[Thread[{Range[6, 20], data}]]
```

[image]